# backbone.js routing issue

Tags: javascript, html, json, backbone.js, handlebars.js

I am very new to js and backbone.js, and I assure you I have searched extensively in docs and on here. I am trying to build a simple site that displays photos (eventually other things) and I want to be able to click a photo to see a different 'page' with another view/template. I cant seem to get this to work and now I am getting a "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'get' of undefined" in my router's photoById method. Code below... THANKS!

//------ main.js

```
var photoListTemplate = Handlebars.compile($('#photo-list-template').html());
var photoTemplate = Handlebars.compile($('#photo-template').html());
var navTemplate = Handlebars.compile($('#navigation-template').html());

var Photo = Backbone.Model.extend({
  defaults: function() {
    return {

    };
  },
  initialize: function(options) {

  }
});
var PhotoCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Photo
});

var PhotoView = Backbone.View.extend({
    events: {

    },

    //tagName: 'td',
    className: 'photo',
    template: photoTemplate,

    initialize: function(options) {
        _.bindAll(this, 'render');
        this.model.on('change', this.render);
    },
    render: function() {
        $(this.el).empty().append(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
        return this;
    }
});

var PhotoCollectionView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: 'table',
    className: 'photo-list',
    template: photoListTemplate,
    events: {

    },
    initialize: function(options) {
        this.collection.on('add remove', this.render, this);
    },
    render: function() {
        $(this.el).empty();
        this.collection.each(function(photo){
            $(this.el).append(new PhotoView({model: photo}).render().el);
        }, this);
        return this;
    }
});

var PhotoRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes: {
        "": "list",
        "photo/:id": "photoById"
    },
    initialize: function(options) {

    },

    allPhotos: function() {
        this.photoList = new PhotoCollection();
        this.photoCollectionView = new PhotoCollectionView({collection: this.photoList});
        this.photList.fetch();
        $('#content').empty().append(this.photoCollectionView.render().el);
    },

    photoById: function(id){
        this.photo = this.photoList.get(id);
        this.photoView = new PhotoView({model: this.photo});
        $('#content').empty().append(this.photoView.render().el);
    }
});

var photos = null;
$.getJSON('http://localhost:3000/photos.json', function(response){
    photos = new PhotoCollection(response);
    $('#container').append(new PhotoCollectionView({collection: photos}).render().el);
    var photoRouter = new PhotoRouter();
    Backbone.history.start();
});
```

/----- index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <title></title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">

    <!-- Place favicon.ico and apple-touch-icon.png in the root directory -->

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
    <script src="js/vendor/modernizr-2.6.2.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <!--[if lt IE 7]>
        <p class="chromeframe">You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please <a href="http://browsehappy.com/">upgrade your browser</a> or <a href="http://www.google.com/chromeframe/?redirect=true">activate Google Chrome Frame</a> to improve your experience.</p>
    <![endif]-->

    <!-- Add your site or application content here -->
    <!-- <p>Replace Me! Replace Me!</p> -->

    <div class='container' id='container'>
    </div>

    <script type="text/x-handlebars-template" id='navigation-template'>
        <div class='navbar'>
            <div class='navbar-inner'>
                <a class='brand' href=#>ohayon</a>
                <ul class='nav'>

                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </script>

    <script type="text/x-handlebars-template" id='photo-template'>
        <div class='lead'>
        <a href='#photo/{{id}}'>{{name}}</a>
        <img src='http://localhost:3000{{image.url}}' height='200' width='200'>
        </div>
    </script>

    <script type="text/x-handlebars-template" id='photo-list-template'>
        <div class='lead'>
        <a href='#photos/{{id}}'>{{name}}</a>
        <img src='http://localhost:3000{{image.url}}'>
        </div>
    </script>

    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/vendor/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
    <script src="js/plugins.js"></script>

    <!-- If we want Boostrap components -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>

    <!-- Templating with Handlebars -->
    <script src="js/handlebars.js"></script>

    <!-- We Need Underscore.js -->
    <script src="js/underscore.js"></script>

    <!-- And Finally Backbone -->
    <script src="js/backbone.js"></script>

    <!-- Your Code goes here -->
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>

    <!-- Google Analytics: change UA-XXXXX-X to be your site's ID. -->
    <script>
        var _gaq=[['_setAccount','UA-XXXXX-X'],['_trackPageview']];
        (function(d,t){var g=d.createElement(t),s=d.getElementsByTagName(t)[0];
        g.src=('https:'==location.protocol?'//ssl':'//www')+'.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
        s.parentNode.insertBefore(g,s)}(document,'script'));
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you've got it coded, there's no guarantee `this.photoList` will have been created by the time you attempt to use it in `photoById`.  You might want to create it in the router's init function:

```
initialize: function(options) {
    this.photoList = photos;
},
```

Also remove a few lines from `allPhotos` -- you don't want to re-create `PhotoCollection` or call `fetch`, since it was already created and populated in the first step of your app.  Should look like this:

```
allPhotos: function() {
    this.photoCollectionView = new PhotoCollectionView({collection: this.photoList});
    $('#content').empty().append(this.photoCollectionView.render().el);
},
```

(One other problem, you're using `container` sometimes and `content` others.)

[It's running here.](http://jsfiddle.net/UePL4/2/)  (I used some dummy data to test with.)